# Organizing Unlocked Packages with conflicting/incompatible components

Tags: salesforcedx

I intend to publish three packages that enable Salesforce integration with a third-party system.  [image]:

- "SF Enrollment Reference" is a common package and should always be installed
- "SF HEDA Contact Reference" should be installed by customers that use [Salesforce EDA](https://www.salesforce.org/highered/data-architecture/)
- "SF Contact Reference" should be installed by customers that do not use Salesforce EDA.

"SF Contact Reference" and "SF HEDA Contact Reference" cannot both be installed onto a given Salesforce org.

My questions are:

- Is it a valid configuration to have "SF Contact Reference" and "SF HEDA Contact Reference" as packages within the *same* project?
- What is the suggested organization of Salesforce  DX projects / packages that I should use? I am thinking:

```
* Project: SF EDA Reference
  * Package: SF HEDA Contact Reference
* Project: SF Reference
  * Package: SF Contact Reference
  * Package: SF Enrollment Reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it a valid configuration to have "SF Contact Reference" and "SF HEDA Contact Reference" as packages within the same project?

Yes, it's perfectly valid. I'd recommend it to help maintain dependencies easier (they all need to be in the sfdx-project.json file, so fewer files is less painful).

> What is the suggested organization of Salesforce DX projects / packages that I should use?

I don't think there's an official recommendation, but you'll probably want to go with something like:

```
* common/enrollment
* extensions/eda-contact
* extensions/contact
```

Or something like that. Whatever you think *looks* okay, probably is. Don't overthink it.

Comment: Part of my confusion arises from the fact that I'm not sure how I'd use ```sfdx force:source:push``` to specify that I want to push different sets of changes, e.g. (enrollment and contact) or (enrollment and eda-contact) ...